# What is the name of the property $f(a+b) = f(f(a)+f(b))$

Tags: terminology

This comes up in a few places. Off the top of my head, this is satisfied by ideals and their radicals as in $r(I+J) = r(r(I)+r(J))$.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Galois connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection#Algebraic_geometry) mentions radicals in Algebraic geomentry.